# How to get URLs (website, facebook, etc.) from soundcloud /users

Tags: soundcloud

As you might know, with Soundcloud API you can get many informations from an User. I success in getting "myspace_name", "discogs_name" and "website". But I want to get the additionals URLs that people can add in the "You on the web" category on their profile (most of the time : facebook, twitter, instagram, etc.)

Do you know where/how I can get it ?

Answer (score 0):

To access user links to website, instagram, facebook etc. you should use:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/users/[USER ID]/web-profiles?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
```

Comment: I didn't find it. Thank you so much !